# Where should I get started when learning how to code Android apps?

Tags: java, android, google-apps

Recently I have grown great interest in apps and how they function, but I want to create one on my own. I have no experience with this and I want to know where should I start and how. I have great knowledge in java but I have no idea what to start learning. Thank you!

**This is my first question so if I have mistakes please tell me and I will fix them or delete the post all together**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, [Civiled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9116330/civiled). Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.gitbook.com/@google-developer-training)
 and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a list of some of the resources I use**

https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-nanodegree-by-google--nd803 (Unfortunately the *entire* course isn't free)

https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-mobile-application-hkustx-comp107x-4 (100% free course)

https://www.edx.org/course/android-developer-capstone-project-galileox-caad005x-0 (100% free course)

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Home/6c236e883cc70912ccdd859173050fc147d409f1 (Because I'm lazy and don't feel like reading text walls sometimes)

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A (100+ videos)

https://www.androidauthority.com/android-studio-tutorial-beginners-637572/

Comment: Bonus resources:  https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ 
    https://developers.google.com/android/for-all/vocab-words/?hl=en 
    https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui